# Linear independence of tensor product basis $\{ v_i \otimes w_j\}$ for $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products, tensors

> Show that the set $\{v_i \otimes w_j\}$ is a linear independent subset of $V\otimes W$ when $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are independent subsets of V and W respectively.

I want to find an error in a proof of this statement.

I've found great proofs of this in the literature, for example [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) and [this book](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf).

They all have the same core of the proof: take a linear form $\varphi_i: V\to \mathbb{F}$ such that $\varphi_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$, which exists thanks to independence of $\{v_i\}$. Then we have a linear function $\phi_i : V\otimes W \to W$ given by $\phi_i(v\otimes w)= \varphi_i(v)w$ which is as close to *projection* $V\otimes W \to W$ as one can hope to get. We can transport any linear relation from $V\otimes W$ to $W$ and use linear independence of $W$.

Details are in the links above.

Okay, so here is the argument I am skeptical of:

> $\DeclareMathOperator{span}{span}$We can assume that $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are bases, instead we can consider $V'=\operatorname{span}\{v_i\}$ and $W'=\operatorname{span}\{w_j\}$.
> Let $F=F(\{v_i\}\times\{w_j\})$ be a free vector space with a basis $\{(v_i,w_j)\}$. We define a bilinear function $\Phi:V\times W \to F$ by
> $$ \Phi(v,w) = \Phi\left(\sum_i a_iv_i,\sum_j b_jw_j\right) = \sum_{i,j}  a_ib_j(v_i,w_j)$$ As $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are bases, therefore the coefficients $a_i,b_j$ are unique, so this function is well defined.
> By the universal property, there is a linear function $\varphi: V\otimes W \to F$ such that $\varphi(v_i\otimes w_j)=\Phi(v_i,w_j)=(v_i,w_j)$. We see that it is an isomorphism, because we can define $\phi^{-1}$ on a basis: $$\phi^{-1}((v_i,w_j))=v_i\otimes w_j$$ which is clearly a linear inverse. Therefore $F$ is isomorphic to $V\otimes W$, so if $\{(v_i,w_j)\}$ is a basis for $F$, $\phi[\{(v_i,w_j)\}] = \{v_i\otimes w_j\}$ must also be a basis.

It uses no *projection* or a variant thereof, and proves the statement almost tautologically. I've tried to find the error, but I couldn't. I have a really hard time accepting this proof, because I haven't seen it anywhere (and there are plenty of places) and it really *feels* logically less demanding as there are no linear functionals used, the isomorphism $F\simeq V\otimes W$ is constructed directly.

Actually, there are a few faulty proofs similar to the above that were already corrected on this site, namely [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475530/basis-of-a-tensor-product) and [here (one of the answers)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78564/basis-for-tensor-products).

If the proof above is correct, can you direct me to the the sources or, ideally, explain why this proof don't appear in the sources I linked to?

Comment: His claim of $(v_i, w_j)$ being basis is not true. The free vector space shall be the infinite dimensional space with every single pair of $(v,w)$ being its basis.

Comment: It's the free vector space spanned on the $(v_i,w_i)$ so it is true, it's not $F(V)$.

Comment: Hmm I mean $V \otimes W$ is usually defined via the quotient of $F(V \times W)$ and also the universal property referred were usually this one. Maybe this proof (i don't know its validity) skips the essential bit of verifying the universal property for $V\times W$, which is different from $F(V\times W)$ and thus makes it appear to be much more easier?