# Tensor rank of matrix $M = \sum_{i = 1}^k w_i (v_i \otimes v_i)$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, matrix-rank, tensor-rank

I encounter this situation while doing the whitening process of a tensor:

> If $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are linearly independent and $w_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$ then the matrix $M = \sum_{i = 1}^k w_i (v_i \otimes v_i)$ has rank $k$.

I can see rank of $M$ should be $\le k$ but not that it has to be exactly $k$. I could even use [Linear independence of tensor product basis $\{ v_i \otimes w_j\}$ for $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ linearly independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460634/linear-independence-of-tensor-product-basis-v-i-otimes-w-j-for-v-i) to show that the $v_i \otimes v_i$ forms a basis on the space of matrices. But I don't see the relation with the rank of the matrix.

Comment: Are $w_i$ scalars?

Comment: @CrabMan Well, the fact that $w_i>0$ is mentioned seems to imply that $w_i$ are real numbers (or at least members of an ordered field). What intrigues me is the "where one can assume that $w_i>0$" afterthought, which appears to indicate that there is some implicit existential quantification over the $w_i$ going on, but that does not make much sense.

Comment: I still think this question lacks clarity: if the vectors $v_i$ live in a real vector space $V$ (which the question does not specify), then the RHS of the equation lives in $V\otimes V$, which is not a space of matrices. Even if $V=\Bbb R^n$ it is not natural to identify $V\otimes V$ with $\operatorname{Mat}_{n,n}(\Bbb R)$, although there are obvious candidates for a vector space isomorphism. Since rank is defined on $\operatorname{Mat}_{n,n}(\Bbb R)$ rather than on $(\Bbb R^n)\otimes(\Bbb R^n)$ one must assume such an identification is chosen (and it does not matter a lot which one).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The rank of a $2$-tensor $T \in \Bbb V \otimes \Bbb V$ coincides with the rank of its matrix representation with respect to any basis of $\Bbb V$, and since $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ is linearly independent we can extend it to a basis $\mathcal B$. What is the matrix representation of $\sum w_i (v_i \otimes v_i)$ with respect to $\mathcal B$?

Comment: It would be $w_i$ for the $v_i \otimes v_i$ appearing in the sum and $0$ otherwise, but what does that tell me about the rank of the matrix

Comment: Right, and the entries correpsonding to the $v_i \otimes v_i$ terms in the matrix representation $[T]$ of $T$ w.r.t. $\mathcal B$ are the $(i, i)$ entries, respectively---so, what is the matrix $[T]$ explicitly?

Comment: oh I see. so there is a notion of representation of a tensor in a basis. In linear algebra I only saw how to represent an endomorphism in a basis.

Comment: Did you encounter the matrix representation of an inner product on a vector space? You can view an inner product on $\Bbb V$ as an element of $\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb V$ (or, more directly, its dual, $\Bbb V^* \otimes \Bbb V^*$).

Comment: N.b. that the change-of-basis formulae differ for matrix representations of endomorphisms and elements of $\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb V$: The former is given by $A \mapsto P^{-1} A P$ and the latter by $S \mapsto P^\top S P$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{ v_i\otimes v_i \}$ is a dependent set then there is a non trivial set of coefficient $\{a_i\}$ such that $\sum_i a_i v_i\otimes v_i=0$, in particular for any $j$ such that $a_j \neq 0$ if you right multiply this by $v_j$ you get
\begin{align*}
0&=0\cdot v_j\\
&=\left(\sum_i a_i v_i\otimes v_i\right)\cdot v_j\\
&=\sum_i a_i (v_i\cdot v_j) v_i
\end{align*}
Now it is clear that $a_j(v_j\cdot v_j)\neq 0$ and therefore the coefficient $a_i(v_i\cdot v_j)$ are non trivial (not all equal to $0$), this means that $v_i$ are dependent.